# Across columns with same suffix, sum if a there is a string match

Tags: r, string, if-statement, dplyr

I have a dataset of lake surveys:

```
structure(list(station_id = c("SB_L004", "SB_L005", "SB_P005", 
"SB_P007", "SB_P008", "SB_P009", "SB_P015"), zone_a_bin1 = c("Shrub, Wetland, Mixed forest", 
"Wetland, Deciduous forest", "Shrub, Wetland, Coniferous forest", 
"Meadow, Wetland, Deciduous forest", "Grass/Lawn", "Grass/Lawn, Wetland", 
"Grass/Lawn, Meadow"), zone_b_bin1 = c("Shrub, Wetland, Mixed forest", 
"Wetland, Deciduous forest", NA, "Mixed forest", NA, NA, "Meadow, Mixed forest"
), zone_c_bin1 = c("Meadow, Wetland, Mixed forest", "Shrub, Wetland, Deciduous forest", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), zone_d_bin1 = c("Meadow, Shrub, Wetland, Coniferous forest", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), zone_a_prop = c(0.1369, 0.2096, 1, 0.898, 
1, 1, 0.5327), zone_b_prop = c(0.2433, 0.4, 0, 0.102, 0, 0, 0.4673
), zone_c_prop = c(0.1109, 0.3904, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), zone_d_prop = c(0.5089, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Here is a subset:

| station_id | zone_a_bin1 | zone_b_bin1 | zone_a_prop | zone_b_prop |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SB_P007 | Meadow, Wetland, Deciduous forest | Mixed forest | 0.898 | 0.102 |
| SB_P015 | Grass/Lawn, Meadow | Meadow, Mixed forest | 0.533 | 0.467 |

where lakes were separated into shoreline zones of varying lengths, so each zone corresponds to a proportion of the total shoreline (columns ending with "prop"). Part of this dataset includes categorical habitat variables recorded as comma-separated values where the column names indicate zone and distance bin from the shore.

For each distance bin, I am trying to calculate the proportion of shoreline that includes each habitat type, corrected for zone proportion. Using the above subset, I am looking for output like:

| station_id | meadow_bin1 |
| --- | --- |
| SB_P007 | 0.898 |
| SB_P015 | 1.0 |

for each habitat type-distance bin combination.
I made the new column with `mutate`, `if_else`, and `str_detect`:

```
dat <- dat %>% 
  mutate(
    meadow_bin1 =
      (if_else(str_detect(zone_a_bin1, regex("Meadow", ignore_case = TRUE)), zone_a_prop, 0, missing = 0) + 
      if_else(str_detect(zone_b_bin1, regex("Meadow", ignore_case = TRUE)), zone_b_prop, 0, missing = 0) + 
      if_else(str_detect(zone_c_bin1, regex("Meadow", ignore_case = TRUE)), zone_c_prop, 0, missing = 0) +
      if_else(str_detect(zone_d_bin1, regex("Meadow", ignore_case = TRUE)), zone_d_prop, 0, missing = 0) 
           )
  )
```

But there are up to 8 zones, at least 8 habitat types, and three distance bins, so the above plan gets unwieldy fast. There has to be a better way, maybe matching the sting of interest ("meadow" in the example above) within columns where the distance bins suffix matches ("_bin1" in the above example) and if the string is present then add the zone proportions together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem becomes much simpler if you alter the structure of the dataset from "short & wide" to "long & narrow". i.e. make more rows but less columns, and by transposing the data this way your calculations become easier.

```
# Load these libraries
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

# Replace 'df' with your actual dataframe

# Transform dataframe to long format
df_long <- df %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = -station_id,
    names_to = c(".value", "zone", "bin"),
    names_pattern = "(zone_[a-z])_(bin[0-9])_(.*)",
    names_sep = "_"
  )

# Split habitat column into multiple rows
df_long <- df_long %>%
  separate_rows(habitat, sep = ", ")

# Calculate proportion for each habitat within each station_id and bin combination
df_final <- df_long %>%
  group_by(station_id, bin, habitat) %>%
  summarise(proportion = sum(prop), .groups = 'drop')
```

To help visulaize, if you printed "df_long" (see above) it should look like this:

```
   station_id zone   bin   prop habitat          
   <chr>      <chr>  <chr> <dbl> <chr>            
 1 SB_L004    zone_a bin1  0.137 Shrub            
 2 SB_L004    zone_a bin1  0.137 Wetland          
 3 SB_L004    zone_a bin1  0.137 Mixed forest     
 ... more rows
```

---

**revised** I tried this at https://rdrr.io/snippets/ and it runs without error but I'm not sure the final grouping is correct:

```
# Load libraries
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

# Assign the structure to df
df <- structure(list(station_id = c("SB_L004", "SB_L005", "SB_P005", 
"SB_P007", "SB_P008", "SB_P009", "SB_P015"), zone_a_bin1 = c("Shrub, Wetland, Mixed forest", 
"Wetland, Deciduous forest", "Shrub, Wetland, Coniferous forest", 
"Meadow, Wetland, Deciduous forest", "Grass/Lawn", "Grass/Lawn, Wetland", 
"Grass/Lawn, Meadow"), zone_b_bin1 = c("Shrub, Wetland, Mixed forest", 
"Wetland, Deciduous forest", NA, "Mixed forest", NA, NA, "Meadow, Mixed forest"
), zone_c_bin1 = c("Meadow, Wetland, Mixed forest", "Shrub, Wetland, Deciduous forest", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), zone_d_bin1 = c("Meadow, Shrub, Wetland, Coniferous forest", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), zone_a_prop = c(0.1369, 0.2096, 1, 0.898, 
1, 1, 0.5327), zone_b_prop = c(0.2433, 0.4, 0, 0.102, 0, 0, 0.4673
), zone_c_prop = c(0.1109, 0.3904, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), zone_d_prop = c(0.5089, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

# Load libraries
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

# Assign the structure to df
# ... (same as before)

# Transform dataframe to long format - step 1 for "bin1" columns
df_long_bin1 <- df %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = ends_with("bin1"),
    names_to = "zone",
    names_prefix = "zone_",
    values_to = "habitat"
  ) %>%
  mutate(bin = "bin1")

# Transform dataframe to long format - step 2 for "prop" columns
df_long_prop <- df %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = ends_with("prop"),
    names_to = "zone",
    names_prefix = "zone_",
    values_to = "prop"
  ) %>%
  mutate(bin = "prop")

# Join the two dataframes together
df_long <- full_join(df_long_bin1, df_long_prop, by = c("station_id", "zone", "bin"))

# Split habitat column into multiple rows
df_long <- df_long %>%
  separate_rows(habitat, sep = ", ")

# Filter out rows where bin is "prop" and habitat is NA
df_long <- df_long %>%
  filter(!(bin == "prop" & is.na(habitat)))

# Calculate proportion for each habitat within each station_id and zone combination
df_final <- df_long %>%
  group_by(station_id, zone, habitat) %>%
  summarise(proportion = sum(prop, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'drop')

# Print the result
print(df_final)
```

The result looked like this so you may need to tweak the above.

```
   station_id zone   habitat           proportion
   <chr>      <chr>  <chr>                  <dbl>
 1 SB_L004    a_bin1 Mixed forest               0
 2 SB_L004    a_bin1 Shrub                      0
 3 SB_L004    a_bin1 Wetland                    0
 4 SB_L004    b_bin1 Mixed forest               0
 5 SB_L004    b_bin1 Shrub                      0
 6 SB_L004    b_bin1 Wetland                    0
 7 SB_L004    c_bin1 Meadow                     0
 8 SB_L004    c_bin1 Mixed forest               0
 9 SB_L004    c_bin1 Wetland                    0
10 SB_L004    d_bin1 Coniferous forest          0
# ... with 38 more rows
```

The bottom line, and important message, is that to avoid unbearably complex code you need to transform your df from a wide/short structure into a narrow/long structure. Once the data is "normalized" the code to group/aggregate numbers will be far simpler.

Comment: Thanks for your response, although I cannot get your 'pivot_longer' code to work: 'If you supply multiple names in `names_to` you must also supply one of `names_sep` or  `names_pattern`'. To try to make this work, I removed the last line ('names_sep') and edited the sample data to have similar column names (now in the format '(zone_[a-z}_(bin[0-9])_(habitat or prop), and the error is: 'Can't combine `zone_a_bin1_habitat` <character> and `zone_a_bin1_prop` <double>' . Also, the columns ending in '_prop' apply to every bin within the same zone, though I can address each bin separately.

Comment: OK. I have a revised approach, but please note I am not attempting to write final code, only to point out the need to transform your data from wide to narrow (pivoted to unpivoted)  once you have the transform properly laid out the aggregation should be simple.

Comment: Thank you so much - I was able to get everything working by using this example. I prevented an all-zero final table by renaming the 'zone' columns so they matched between the '_prop' and '_bin1' pivoted data, and a couple other minor edits. Thanks again!

Comment: Pleased to hear you got a result. Now you will know to avoid wide layouts for aggregations. :-)